# pygame Error in keeping score

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, 2d-games, tmx

I'm making a platform game for class and I used this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTmJfWdZzbo) as my guide. However, I'm having trouble keeping score. Here is my [code](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5811). The problem is that once I hit a coin, instead of adding only 1 point, it increments continuously. Please help!

Comment: Please add in the minimal amount of code necessary for us to replicate your error.

Comment: it has been solved already. thanks anyway. :) @Jhecht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this section where you check to add to the score:

```
if self.isRight == True:
    self.score += 1
```

You forgot to set `self.isRight` back to False. Change your code to this:

```
if self.isRight == True:
    self.score +=1
    self.isRight = False
```